# Microsoft graph API old and new

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there any difference between what one can get from

https://graph.windows.net vs https://graph.microsoft.com?

It seems that there's different versions for one, .net is under version 1.6 and .com under 1.0.

They both seem to work with the v2.0 auth scopes, but do they work the same way?

Thanks to anyone that can shed some light!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Microsoft Graph (https://graph.microsoft.com) you can access the data that is exposed in the Azure AD graph API (https://graph.windows.net) and, in addition to that, access data from services like Outlook/Exchange, OneDrive, SharePoint, OneNote, Planner and more (for both consumer and commercial). 
The recommendation is to use Microsoft Graph API. That said, there is still a small percentage of functionality that is only available in the Azure AD Graph and we are working hard to close the gap.

Comment: Thanks Yina, do you know if the scopes work the same using the v2 oauth between the two apis?

Comment: Yes - the scopes work the same way in terms of the level of access each scope provides.  Please see https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes for details.

Comment: We just published a blog post on this: http://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph